# How to imap a character in Vim based on previous character

Tags: vim, editor, vi

I have created the following mapping to simulate behaviour in some IDEs where when you insert `{` after a function declaration like  `foo()` a closing `}` and empty row is inserted automatically and cursor is set to the empty row on tabbed position.

```
:imap { {<CR><CR>} <up><Tab>
```

This of course does this behavior when I insert `{` in any context. How do I do it based on the previously inserted character? Must be a vim script function involved?
Note: I do not want to use external vim plugins.

Comment: It is not actual answer to your question, but similar behavior can be achieved with snippets (e.g. [snipmate plugin](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate))

Comment: Let me get this straight, you want to accomplish some IDE like functionality that sniff a line's syntax in one line of your `~/.vimrc` file? This will lead to naive `imap` which is bound to fail in many cases. This is a balancing act, you either get a simple mapping that is only correct part of the time or you use a more advanced solution that requires a function or plugin that works much better. What is your issue with against a function or using a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

IDEs usually do this expansion after typing {<CR>, which is easy to do in vimscript:

```
:imap {<CR> {<CR><CR>} <up><Tab>
```

This will not expand if you keep on typing other things on the same line.

The caveat is that there's a small delay when typing a { with this mapping. See the 'timeout' and 'timeoutlen' options for details.

Comment: @SJMP: <CR> is an abbreviation for carriage return. See `:h key-notation` for more.

Answer (score 1):

These code snippets give you the character just before and just after the cursor when in insert mode:

```
let previous_character = getline(".")[col(".")-2]
let next_character     = getline(".")[col(".")-1]
```

You can use them in an `<expr>` mapping:

```
:inoremap <expr> { getline(".")[col(".")-2] == " " ? "{^M}^OO" : "{"
```

The pointless mapping above checks if the character before the cursor is a space before deciding if it inserts a `{` or an expanded `{}`.

If you want a "smart" mapping you won't be able to avoid writing one or more functions. The one I use, for example, is 69 lines long.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find multiple approaches and a list of plugins on the [Automatically append closing characters](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_append_closing_characters) Vim Tips Wiki page. Note that though there are simplistic solutions, they usually have some downsides, and the whole approach is unfortunately broken in Vim 7.4 with regards to undo.